# How does Lagom manage communication patterns?

Tags: lagom

I'm referring to the "Managing  Communication Patterns" section of Reactive Microservices Architecture by Jonas Boner.

Usually when communicating between services (ESB is one example), one would need:
1) A queue for pub-sub communication, and to queue up events for back pressure and fault tolerance 
2) A routing layer - Camel Or Akka Streams
3) A mediation later for communicating with different protocols - Camel is one example.

How does Lagom handle the above?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure you "usually" need routing and mediation within the message bus. Jonas Bonér points out that publish/subscribe is a very useful addition to using HTTP calls for microservices. This is provided by Lagom in form of the [message bus](https://www.lagomframework.com/documentation/1.3.x/scala/MessageBroker.html#Message-Broker-Support).
This in accordance with the "[smart endpoints, dumb pipes](https://martinfowler.com/articles/microservices.html#SmartEndpointsAndDumbPipes)" approach.

If you want to follow a different approach and put mediation and orchestration in the bus, rather than in services and possibly their anti-corruption layers, you could leverage Camel and/or RabbitMQ or the likes, but there's no Lagom-specific integration. You'd just use the Scala (or Java) connectors they provide.